# Redirect to directory if directory exists using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have about 250 directories off of public_html that I want to move into /clients/. Since the original URL's e.g. mysite.com/bob are already used in the client's printed marketing materials, I need to keep them accessible. I'd like for when someone goes to mysite.com/bob (example), htaccess checks if mysite.com/agents/bob exists, then redirect to it, if it does. I've checked SO posts and came up with this so far, but am at a block trying to get it to work for any name scenario.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /error_page.php

## check if path exists
## example: mysite.com/agents/bob

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

## if mysite.com/agents/bob exists, redirect mysite.com/bob 
## to mysite.com/agents/bob    

## The code below works - but just for bob. Want it to work for any name 
## e.g. mysite.com/tom, mysite.com/fred - to be redirected to 
## mysite.com/agents/tom, mysite.com/agents/fred respectively
## if mysite.com/agents/tom, mysite.com/agents/fred exist on the webserver

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^bob\/?$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/agents\/bob" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your code , Replace last line :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/?$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/agents\/bob" [R=301,L]
```

With this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/agents/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/error_page.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/?$     /agents/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, the code above will redirect all request to `/agents/` directory and exclude any request contains `/agents/` to avoid looping then if the request is wrong error page will handle that and i excluded as well from this rule.

If you want to check first in  `/agents/` then in another location let me know to add another rules.

Clear browser cached the test it .

**UPDATE :**

Try this instead :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/bob/agents/
RewriteRule ^bob/(.+)\/?$     /agents/bob/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/agents/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/agents%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    /agents%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The code above will check any request not contains `/agents/` even to `site.com/index` then check `/agents/` directory , if it is exist ok ,it will be redirect to `/agents/` , otherwise will handle it as it is .

If you want to exclude `index` let me know

Comment: Your changes did redirect to the test subdirectory: /agents/bob  correctly.

However, now when my main page is loaded, mysite.com, the css and js files are no longer loaded. 

Also, if I go to a page that does not exist, like mysite/noname, I receive a "mysite.com redirected you too many times" error.

And it tries to load the error page in mysite.com/agents/error_page.php instead of mysite.com/error_page.php

I cleared the cache and cookies with each test with same results.

Comment: @user2413654 ok , you want only request that contains bob to be checked in agents/bob/ right?

Comment: Right, if request made to mysite.com/agentname  - check if mysite.com/agents/agentname exists, if it does, redirect to mysite.com/agents/agentname. 

But I also have requests to other static directories that are not agent names that still need to resolve. For example: mysite.com/other. 

So, is it possible to first check as above, and if not exist, then check if request is a directory, and allow to resolve it is, if not, direct to error page in root.

Comment: Ok , so the request mysyite.com/whatever , first look in mysite.com/agents/whatever , then mysite.com/whatever right?

Comment: Correct. Then  if neither directory exists, then redirect to error page.

Comment: @user2413654 yes , test it and let me know the result

Comment: Ok, site works normally for display now. However, I have a test directory for mysite.com/agents/bob. No directory for mysite.com/bob. When I go to mysite.com/bob, I get the error page, it does not redirect to mysite.com/agents/bob.

Comment: @user2413654 just replace this line RewriteRule ^bob\/?$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/agents\/bob" [R=301,L]  at ur original code with my latest code

Comment: @user2413654 make sure that bob is not a directory because you've already excluded by ur orignal code , this line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d , so if you want to check files + directories in agents directory , remove this line at original code

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for all of your assistance.